# Running Flux operations in parallel

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a list of items that I need to retrieve data for from different sources, combine, and return. The items are totally independent and fetching the data will take the most time so I want it to be done in parallel. I thought I could do this with Reactor using Flux.fromStream() and Mono.zipWith() but instead it seems to wait for each item to complete before starting the next one.

Here's a test I wrote to illustrate the problem. The code makes 10 sandwiches and simulates a random delay in fetching the peanut butter and jelly:

```
class FluxOrderingTest {
  private final Random random = new Random();

  @Test
  void testAsyncSandwich() {
    Flux<String> sandwiches = Flux.fromStream(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).boxed())
            .flatMap(number -> getJelly(number).zipWith(getPeanutButter(number)))
            .map(this::makeSandwich);

    StepVerifier.create(sandwiches)
            .expectNextCount(10)
            .verifyComplete();
  }

  private String makeSandwich(Tuple2<String, String> ingredients) {
    System.out.printf("Combined %s with %s%n", ingredients.getT1(), ingredients.getT2());
    return "Sandwich";
  }

  private Mono<String> getPeanutButter(Integer number) {
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> withDelay("the peanut butter for " + number));
  }

  private Mono<String> getJelly(Integer number) {
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> withDelay("the jelly for " + number));
  }

  private String withDelay(String s) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Got " + s);
    return s;
  }
}
```

In the output I expected the sandwiches to complete out of order because of the random time it takes to get the ingredients. But instead, Reactor finishes each sandwich in order.

```
Got the jelly for 1
Got the peanut butter for 1
Combined the jelly for 1 with the peanut butter for 1
Got the jelly for 2
Got the peanut butter for 2
Combined the jelly for 2 with the peanut butter for 2
Got the jelly for 3
Got the peanut butter for 3
Combined the jelly for 3 with the peanut butter for 3
Got the jelly for 4
Got the peanut butter for 4
Combined the jelly for 4 with the peanut butter for 4
Got the jelly for 5
Got the peanut butter for 5
Combined the jelly for 5 with the peanut butter for 5
Got the jelly for 6
Got the peanut butter for 6
Combined the jelly for 6 with the peanut butter for 6
Got the jelly for 7
Got the peanut butter for 7
Combined the jelly for 7 with the peanut butter for 7
Got the jelly for 8
Got the peanut butter for 8
Combined the jelly for 8 with the peanut butter for 8
Got the jelly for 9
Got the peanut butter for 9
Combined the jelly for 9 with the peanut butter for 9
Got the jelly for 10
Got the peanut butter for 10
Combined the jelly for 10 with the peanut butter for 10
```

How to I schedule the ingredients to be fetched all at the same time since I don't care about the final ordering?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is synthetic and a real code with an actual IO would behave differently because it would use different *Schedulers* for IO. Though it depends on how you do IO, of course. If you use reactive IO you shouldn't have any problem.

In your case it's just a single scheduler that runs everything immediately, i.e., in one thread.

Try to subscribe on different schedulers:

```
.flatMap(number -> 
    getJelly(number)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .zipWith(
            getPeanutButter(number)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        )
        
)
```